# c++ написал прогу по фану а там

Tags: c++, linux

[image: вывод программы]написал прогу по фану на с++ а она почему то не вызывает ошибку 0_0

```
#ifndef IS_GUARD_
#define IS_GUARD_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define RETURN return 0;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"ru");

    int iChetOrNo;
    cin>>iChetOrNo;
    if(iChetOrNo % 2==0) {
        cout<<"Число четное"<<endl;
    }
    else {
        cout<<"Число не четное"<<endl;
    }

    RETURN;
}
#endif //IS_GUARD_
```

по идеи если ввести не целочисленное число то должна вызываться ошибка а она пишет:
  Число Четное

Comment: Если ввести не целое число, считается только часть до точки, остаток останется в буфере ввода. Переменная-то у вас - `int`...

Comment: т.е. у меня все норм с Ubuntu?
и да я хочу вызвать исключение каким образом мне это сделать?

Comment: @jbcdgb так http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно делают вот так:

```
cin >> iChetOrNo;
if (!cin) {/* выйти с ошибкой */}
```

---

Либо можно приписать в начале `main` это:

```
cin.exceptions(cin.failbit | cin.badbit);
```

Тогда `cin` будет бросать сам исключение при ошибке.

Answer (score 4):

Попытка ввести строковый литерал в целочисленную переменную приводит к тому, что в ней оказывается число 0. А ноль - четное число.

Comment: Эм.. Почему в ней должен оказаться 0? Вроде это никто не обещал. Да и что-то я не помню, чтобы оно так работало.

Comment: @Qwertiy я, честно говоря, не знаю почему там 0, может быть как заглушка для неудавшегося ввода, но экспериментальные данные показывают что там таки оказывается 0

Comment: http://codepad.org/8cZLnNho

Comment: А как на этом сайте программа получает ввод с консоли? Сдается мне что никак, тогда переменная просто не инициализируется и, естественно, выводится мусор. Я сравнивал результаты попыток вывести неинициализированную переменную и переменную, которой пытались при помощи ```cin``` передать строковый литерал. Во втором случае стабильно 0

Comment: @Qwertiy Там правила какие-то хитрые. Похоже, если в потоке EOF - то не инициалируется, а если неподходящие символы, то 0. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/393ad81bbf96f47c

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да, на том сайте EOF. Странно, может и так. Но я ни разу не видел, чтобы подобное как-то гарантировалось. Подтверждение сможешь найти?

Comment: [Вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605070/cin-in-c-trying-to-assign-string-values-to-an-int-variable) объясняется.
tl;dr cin в конце концов вызывает strtol, который возвращает 0 потому что преобразование не удалось